# SQLite query returning false

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, sqlite, python-3.4

So for my project I'm trying to have the user type something into a text box and if it's equal to what is stored in the database then it will tell them it's true. However at the moment even when the correct thing is input it will return false. This is the current code for the part that gets the answer, returns and compares it:

```
    def submit():
        answerA=entry_A.get()
        answerB=entry_B.get()
        answerC=entry_C.get()
        answerD=entry_D.get()
        answerE=entry_E.get()
        answerF=entry_F.get()
        print(answerA,", ",answerB,", ",answerC,", ",answerD,", ",answerE,", ",answerF)

        labelA=cursor.execute\
        ("select labelA from diagramLabels where diaName == 'plantCell'").fetchall()
        con.commit()
        if labelA == answerA:
            print("Answer A is correct")
        else:
            print("Answer A is false")
```

[And this is the result it gives in Idle, along with what's in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb4QW.png)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()`.
`fetchall()` returns a number of rows (like this: `(('nucleus',),)` ) whereas `fetchone()` will only return one row.
You will then get something like this: `('nucleus',)`
You can compare it with `labelA[0] == answerA` then.